# Uploading images from React to the Laravel backend empties the request body

Tags: reactjs, laravel, validation, inertiajs

I'm developing an ecommerce website with Laravel and React using Inertia.js. I've created a component for image uploads using Dropzone. This component is used on a page within a form, which serves both for creating and updating products.

Regarding product creation, there are no issues, and everything works as expected. The problem arises when I try to update products. If I only modify the fields without adding images, the update works perfectly. However, when I add one or more images, validation errors are triggered on all fields, as if they were left empty.

I tried to do a 'dump and die' of the $request in the Request class and noticed that it's empty when images are included. I also used console.log statements in the frontend to check that the data was correctly sent and everything seems fine. I assume the issue lies in how I'm sending the data, but I can't pinpoint the exact error.

This is my code

Image upload component

```
export default function ImageUploader({ className, setData, data }) {
    const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
    const [rejected, setRejected] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setData({ ...data, images: files });
    }, [files]);
    //[JSON.stringify(...files)]
    const onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) => {
        if (acceptedFiles?.length) {
            setFiles((previousFiles) => [
                ...previousFiles,
                ...acceptedFiles.map((file) =>
                    Object.assign(file, { preview: URL.createObjectURL(file) }),
                ),
            ]);
        }

        if (rejectedFiles?.length) {
            setRejected((previousFiles) => [
                ...previousFiles,
                ...rejectedFiles,
            ]);
        }
    }, []);
    const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({
        onDrop,
        accept: {
            'image/*': [],
        },
        maxSize: 1024 * 1000,
    });

    const removeFile = (name) => {
        setFiles((files) => files.filter((file) => file.name !== name));
    };

    const removeRejected = (name) => {
        setRejected((files) => files.filter(({ file }) => file.name !== name));
    };

    return (
        <>
            <InputLabel
                className={`text-xl`}
                htmlFor="images"
                value="Immagini"
            />

            <p className="pt-2">Dimensioni massime: 1 Mb</p>

            <div
                {...getRootProps({
                    className,
                })}
            >
                <input
                    {...getInputProps()}
                    id="images"
                    name="images"
                    form="productForm"
                />
                {isDragActive ? (
                    <p>Trascina i file qui ...</p>
                ) : (
                    <p>Trascina qui i file, o clicca per selezionarli</p>
                )}
            </div>

            ....
            ....
            ....
}
```

Data Form

```
export default function ProductForm({ auth, product, categories }) {
    const { data, setData, post, put, processing, errors } = useForm(
        product
            ? {
                  name: product.name,
                  description: product.description,
                  sku: product.sku,
                  price: product.price,
                  discounted_price: product.discounted_price,
                  cost: product.cost,
                  quantity: product.quantity,
                  track_quantity: product.track_quantity,
                  sell_out_of_stock: product.sell_out_of_stock,
                  status: product.status,
                  category_id: product.category_id,
                  images: [],
              }
            : {
                  name: '',
                  description: '',
                  sku: '',
                  price: '',
                  discounted_price: '',
                  cost: '',
                  quantity: '',
                  track_quantity: true,
                  sell_out_of_stock: false,
                  status: '',
                  category_id: '',
                  images: [],
              },
    );

    const submit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (product) {
            put(route('admin.products.update', product));
            return;
        }
        post(route('admin.products.store'));
    };

    ....
    ....
    ....
<ImageUploader
    setData={setData}
    data={data}
    className="mt-2 rounded-lg border border-gray-400 bg-gray-100 p-16 text-center shadow-lg"
/>
```

Request class

```
public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return $this->user()->can('update', $this->route('product'));
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule|array<mixed>|string>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        dd($this->request);
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'description' => 'required|string',
            'sku' =>
                'required|string|unique:products,sku,'.$this->route('product')->id,
            'track_quantity' => 'sometimes|nullable|boolean',
            'quantity' => 'required_if:track_quantity,true|nullable|int',
            'sell_out_of_stock' => 'required_if:track_quantity,true|boolean',
            'category_id' => 'required|int|exists:categories,id',
            'price' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
            'cost' => 'sometimes|nullable|numeric',
            'discounted_price' => 'sometimes|nullable|numeric',
            'status' => 'required|string|in:active,draft,review',
            'images' => 'sometimes|nullable|array',
        ];
    }
```

update method

```
public function update(UpdateProductRequest $request, Product $product)
    {
        $product->update(
            $request
                ->safe()
                ->collect()
                ->filter(fn($value) => !is_null($value))
                ->except(['images'])
                ->all()
        );

        $images = $request->file('images');

        if ($images !== null) {
            foreach ($images as $image) {
                Cloudinary::upload($image->getRealPath(), [
                    'transformation' => [
                        'width' => '700',
                        'quality' => 'auto',
                        'crop' => 'scale',
                    ]
                ])->getSecurePath();

                $product->attachMedia($image);
            }
        }

        return to_route('admin.products.index')->with('message', 'Prodotto aggiornato con successo');
    }
```

[console.log data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHsiv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inertia will automatically convert your form to a `FormData` object.

https://inertiajs.com/file-uploads#form-data-conversion

> When making Inertia requests that include files (even nested files),
> Inertia will automatically convert the request data into a FormData
> object. This conversion is necessary in order to submit a
> multipart/form-data request via XHR.

But Laravel doesn't support the `PUT` method for `multipart/form-data` so you have to use `POST` and spoof the request using `_method: 'put'`.

https://inertiajs.com/file-uploads#multipart-limitations

> Uploading files using a multipart/form-data request is not natively
> supported in some server-side frameworks when using the PUT,PATCH, or
> DELETE HTTP methods. The simplest workaround for this limitation is to
> simply upload files using a POST request instead.
>
> However, some frameworks, such as Laravel and Rails, support form
> method spoofing, which allows you to upload the files using POST, but
> have the framework handle the request as a PUT or PATCH request. This
> is done by including a _method attribute in the data of your request.

So your code should look something like this. I believe Laravel will handle interpreting it as a PUT request automatically.

```js
// Post the form, but tell Laravel to treat it as a PUT request.
post(route('admin.products.update', product), {
    _method: 'put',
});
```

Comment: Thank you, you've pinpointed the issue. I tried modifying the code and using 
`router.post(`/admin/products/${product.id}/`, {  _method: 'put', data })`
 since it seems that useForm's post method doesn't accept the _method parameter. Now the problem is that when I submit the form, I always get redirected to the page I came from without receiving any errors. I attempted to use dump and die in the controller's update method, but it doesn't trigger, so I presume it doesn't even reach the method."

Comment: What does your network tab say? What's the HTTP code? 403? Anything in the logs?

Comment: I managed to solve it, the solution was to add the _method key directly inside the data object. Thanks for your help.